# Unable to resolve Experience Site CSP Errors in sandbox

Tags: error, experience-cloud, csp

I'm not sure what has changed in Experience Cloud but suddenly I'm getting CSP errors for some images that I'm linking to in an HTML component. I'm struggling to resolve these errors and get the images to display because:

1. In Settings -> Security & Privacy -> CSP Errors, there are no errors listed for me to Whitelist a URL or approve the resource.
2. I've added the image base URL to the CSP trusted sites, and it has no effect on resolving the CSP issues

What is extra strange is that these steps DID work in Production, but it isn't working in Sandbox. I thought maybe it was because sandbox URLs were recently changed to include "sandbox" in it, but my image URLs are referencing Production resources so they wouldn't have been affected.

Has anyone faced these stubborn CSP errors in a sandbox before or have any ideas on how to resolve them permanently?

### **The CSP Error**

[image]

### **The broken images as a result of the CSP error:**

[image]

### **I don't see any CSP errors to approve/resolve in the Settings & Privacy area???**

[image]

### **I have tried adding the URL to the CSP Trusted Sites**

[image]

Comment: Any luck on on resolving this issue? My team is running into the same and followed the same steps as you.